# Growth of |logx| versus of 1/x

Tags: real-analysis, integration, logarithms

Do you think there is a number k s.t. $\int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{|log(x)|^{k}}{x}d\mu$ will converge,where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure?

If you don't know ,can you at least give me some reference for the relative growth of those two? All I found was general discussions of growth.

Also, is there a number k s.t. $\int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{e^x}{x^k}d\mu$ converges?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{\lvert\log(x)\rvert^{k}}{x}d\mu\ge\int_{(1,\infty)}\frac{\log^{k}(x)}{x}d\mu=\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{k}d\mu$

There is no $k$ so that the final integral converges.

Since $e^{x}>1$ on $(0,\infty)$ then:

$\int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{e^{x}}{x^{k}}d\mu>\int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{1}{x^{k}}d\mu$

but there is no $k$ so that the final integral converges.